# Top menu bar is not getting selected

Tags: magento-1.7

Top menu bar is not getting selected.

\app\design\frontend\default\new_design_test\template\tm\custommenu\top.phtml

```
   <?php foreach ($_categories as $_category): ?>
        <?php echo $this->drawCustomMenuItem($_category) ?>
    <?php endforeach ?>
```

Not understanding Where to write selected code?

Can anyone tell why menu is not getting selected?

Comment: check this method "drawCustomMenuItem"

Comment: @St3phan thank u so much ... it worked great :)